# CSS Div Static and Auto Width for two divs

Tags: css

I have two divs, say : `#left` and `#right` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpahadi/phxL5L1k/)

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='left'>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id='right'>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

I want `#right` div to be always `200px` whatever the screen size be.
I want `#left` div to automatically fit the screen of left area.

```
#container,#left,#right{
    margin: 0;padding:0;
}
#container{font-size : 0}
#left{
    display : inline-block;
    width : auto;
    background : #00bbbb;
    font-size: 19px

}
#right{
    display : inline-block;
    width : 200px !important;
    background: #eee;
    font-size: 19px
}
```

I did in jQuery by :

```
var _width = $('#container').width();
var _custom = _width - 200;
$("#left").css('width',_custom);
```

But, I want to know if this is possible pure CSS because of performance issues (I have a lot) and I have to modify them at every time window resizes. In short, they are not cool in this scenario.

Any ideas?

> Note: This is not a progress bar and the Right one is static, not left!!!

Comment: For a pure CSS solution, you can invert the order of the html elements and then float right the div #right. Check my update

Comment: Ps. You can't use the trick of parent font:0 and children display:inline-block because you need to float one of the elements in this case to make it work :)

Comment: @benjour Some people might not be right or answering your question correctly. But at least be polite to the people taking out time to help you. No one here is getting paid to help you, I hope you understand what I mean :) Good day! (PS: I wrote this comment, since I saw your comment on one of the answers, which the user deleted now)

Comment: @TheUknown Sure. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with just CSS. Set a height for each div.

```
.left{
    float:left;
    background: #efefef;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    }

.right{
    overflow:hidden; 
    background-color:#000;
    height: 100px;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

To achieve what you are asking and having one right div of 200px fixed and the left to fill the rest, you can invert the order of the html elements and then float right the div #right which is first in the html order.

```
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>


.left{
    background: #efefef;
    height:50px;
}

.right{
    overflow:hidden; 
    background-color:#000;
    height:50px;  
    float:right;
    width:200px;

}
```

**JSFIDDLE** - what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/8pk4K/2040/

Comment: Please revise the question and make it more readable. What is exactly you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#right {
 float:right;
 width:200px;
}
#left {
 margin-right:240px;
}
```

Float & margins